# reverse axis direction for google motion chart

Tags: google-visualization

I am creating a gvisMotionChart that displays data from the past 5 years.  I would like the initial state to be the most recent date (ex. 2012) and for the chart to move "backwards" in time.  I know how to set the initial state to the latest date, but that doesn't reverse the time scale at all it just starts the chart at the end of the timeline.

basically, I am looking for a function for the gvisMotionChart that does the same thing as the  "hAxis.direction" function for the google Scatter Chart.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Thanks!!